# Оптимизируйте код python

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
year = ['Крыса', 'Буйвол', 'Тигр', 'Кролик(Кот)', 'Дракон', 'Змея', 'Лошадь', 'Овца', 'Обезьяна', 'Петух', 'Собака', 'Свинья']
color = {0: 'Белый (Металл)', 1: 'Белый (Металл)', 2: 'Черный (Вода)', 3: 'Черный (Вода)', 4: 'Голубой (Дерево)', 5: 'Голубой (Дерево)', 6: 'Красный (Огонь)', 7: 'Красный (Огонь)', 8: 'Желтый (Земля)', 9: 'Желтый (Земля)'}
year_new = int(input())
k = year_new % 10
yk = abs((year_new - 2020) % 12)
st = color[k]
if yk in [0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11] :
    st = st.replace('ый', 'ая').replace('ой', 'ая')
print(st + ' ' + year[yk])
```

как оптимизировать код , чтобы был записан вообще  в самое минимальное кол-во строк ? может можно как то заменить линейные алгоритмы на функции какие нибудь или циклы, чтобы код получился намного кратче?

Comment: Словарь `color` я бы поменял на список -- код бы не поменялся, но выглядел логичнее. А так, код и так кажется достаточно коротким

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
years = ['Крыса', 'Буйвол', 'Тигр', 'Кролик(Кот)', 'Дракон', 'Змея', 'Лошадь', 'Овца', 'Обезьяна', 'Петух', 'Собака', 'Свинья']
colors = ['Белый (Металл)', 'Белый (Металл)', 'Черный (Вода)', 'Черный (Вода)', 'Голубой (Дерево)', 'Голубой (Дерево)', 'Красный (Огонь)', 'Красный (Огонь)', 'Желтый (Земля)', 'Желтый (Земля)']
genders = [False, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False]

year = int(input())

print(colors[year % 10].replace('ый', 'ый' if genders[(year - 2020) % len(genders)] else 'ая').replace('ой', 'ой' if genders[(year - 2020) % len(genders)] else 'ая'), years[(year - 2020) % len(years)])
```

можно чуть покороче:

```
print(colors[year % 10].replace('ый', ('ая', 'ый')[genders[(year - 2020) % 12]]).replace('ой', ('ая', 'ой')[genders[(year - 2020) % 12]]), years[(year - 2020) % 12])
```

можно еще чуть покороче, но тогда надо будет изменить основные списки:

```
years = ['Обезьяна', 'Петух', 'Собака', 'Свинья', 'Крыса', 'Буйвол', 'Тигр', 'Кролик(Кот)', 'Дракон', 'Змея', 'Лошадь', 'Овца',]
colors = ['Белый (Металл)', 'Белый (Металл)', 'Черный (Вода)', 'Черный (Вода)', 'Голубой (Дерево)', 'Голубой (Дерево)', 'Красный (Огонь)', 'Красный (Огонь)', 'Желтый (Земля)', 'Желтый (Земля)']
genders = [False, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, False,]

year = int(input())

print(colors[year % 10].replace('ый', ('ая', 'ый')[genders[year % 12]]).replace('ой', ('ая', 'ой')[genders[year % 12]]), years[year % 12])
```

Comment: А перевод цвета в женский род куда дели?)

Comment: а, пардонте, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Не нравятся мне эти простыни кода в одну строку... Да и дублирование кода, например `(year - 2020) % len(`... Код должен быть понятным для чтения человеку, а не интерпретатору :D

Comment: так автор спрашивает `как оптимизировать код , чтобы был записан вообще в самое минимальное кол-во строк?`, можно конечно таблицу на 240 элементов сделать и тогда решение в 1 строчку будет очень красивое и короткое, иначе можно сделать красивое и понятное решение, но строчек в 5

Comment: @Zhihar, простите, если вам показалось, что я против вашего ответы был. Если бы он мне не понравился, минус поставил бы. Просто, за что питон любят -- zen, например `"Simple is better than complex."`. А такие "оптимизации" кода это его усложнение для себя и других программистов и разве что повод повыпендриваться :) Вспомнилось, на stepic одно время было популярным решать задания через eval/exec, так всегда получалось по меркам системы писать код на минимум операторов. Думаю, их система просто не умела смотреть в код в строках у eval/exec. Выглядел такой код как фарш из операторов :D

Comment: @gil9red, да все в порядке, я тоже предпочитаю все таки несколько строк вместо одной, но раз автор просил - вот вам код, по идее у кода должна быть минимальная функциональность (т.е. делать только то, что требуется и не больше) и тогда он код выглядит и понятно и красиво и просто

Comment: Длинные строки - зло. К тому же, сэкономили всего 26 байт (3% от изначального размера), при этом значительно ухудшилась читаемость - так себе оптимизация.

Comment: @insolor, ну вам не угодишь :) можно заранее сгенерировать таблицу из 240 элементов и тогда 1 строчка кода будет очень короткая - `print(table[year % 240])` :)

Comment: Мне можно угодить: в данном случае нужно просто оставить как есть (кроме color, который нужно в список переделать). Больше тут нечего оптимизировать.

Comment: @insolor, ну если уж придираться, тогда можно было бы для `yk = abs((year_new - 2020) % 12)` сдвинуть списки направо на 4 и тогда было бы `yk = year_new % 12`, а `abs` вообще не нужен